# Don't allow jquery's accordion to make its container grow

Tags: jquery, size, accordion

I have a  which contains a accordion inside.

It works fine, but when I open an accordion section that contains a table that apparently needs more width, it re-sizes the container.

How can avoid this?

Thx.

Comment: Can't - that's how browsers work.

Comment: Can't use scroll bars to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

What if you make a container div around this accordian, and set the (max-)width/height to exactly what you want.. Without any code/jsfiddle that's the best I can do.

---

**EDIT:** is there any problem with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/RJNpg/)?